# What is an elegant way to formally define a k-hop subgraph?

Tags: graph-theory, notation

I am interested in elegantly formalizing a k-hop subgraph.
I.e. a subgraph to a graph where all vertices in said subgraph are the ones that are at maximum k steps away from some vertex $v_0$ in the original graph.

The best thing I can come up with is something along these lines:
Given a graph $G = \langle V, E \rangle$, define a subgraph $G_s \subseteq G$ s.t. $\forall v_s \in G_s: \operatorname{dist}(v_0, v_s) \leq k$.

How can you experess this a little more mathematically, ideally without the $\operatorname{dist}()$ function.

Thanks :)

Comment: This is normally called the ball / neighbourhood of radius $k$ of / centered at $v_0$. You need the distance function to describe it though... (or something equivalent to it).

Comment: Notation: use `\langle V, E \rangle` for better angle brackets: $\langle V, E \rangle$.

Comment: Any definition of this subgraph will be equivalent to bounding the distance from $v_0$ from above by $k$, where distance is the usual discrete function measuring shortest path between vertices. I would just call it the (closed) ball centered at $v_0$ of radius $k$, and denote it $B_k(v_0)$.